# Twilio - Code during a call

Tags: twilio

I am using Twilio and I would like to create an application which would allow two users to interact with a programmed agent.

For instance here would be the flow of the application :

- User 1 make a call using the phone number of User 2
- User 2 answers the phone
- The agent makes an announcement that the call is a special call with some keywords that can be used to interact with the agent

I wanted to use the status callback of the call in order to make a get request on a page with TwiMl code based on Say and gather tags.

I manage to make the call and the callback is received on my server but nothing happens in the call.

For now I am coding in Python with Flask and my code is like this :

```
@app.route('/call', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def call():
    ...

    resp = VoiceResponse()

    with resp.dial(callerId=caller_id) as r:
        r.number(destination_number, status_callback_event='answered',  status_callback='https://myapp.com/call_answered')

    return str(resp)

@app.route('/call_answered', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def call_answered():

    resp = VoiceResponse()
    resp.Say("Hi, you are in a real time managed call")        
    return str(resp)
```

Do you know why ?

Thanks a lot

Mickael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can update a call using the REST API. You can redirect the call to new TwiML to change what is going on. Check out the documentation for updating a call and redirecting to a new URL here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I am using dial to call a real number from my computer but I would like to use gather and say nouns. Do you know if I can do that ?

Comment: Hi Mike, most things are possible, but if you need guidance on a particular feature you're going to need to be a bit more specific. If you want to update your question, ideally with things you have already tried as well as what you are trying to achieve, then I will try to help.

Comment: You can't use `<Gather>` and `<Say>` while two callers are connected directly to each other. When you say you've managed "to make the call and the redirection is received on my server but nothing happens in the call." what do you mean by that? What code do you have right now?

Comment: I added pieces of my code. I mean that on my server I can see that the call is answered but it seems that what I want to do is not supported for now! Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Right, the statusCallback is an asynchronous webhook that doesn't directly affect the call. You can, as I said in the original answer, [modify the live call from that status callback via the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress). Perhaps that is a option? Otherwise, if you want two callers and an agent (automated or otherwise) in a call, you'll need to start with a [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference).